# making tuples from pandas list

Tags: python, pandas

I have got panda list as mentioned below.

```
[post_code  bnf_name                          
 B11 4BW    Salbutamol_Inha 100mcg (200 D) CFF    0.031059
 B12 9LP    Paracet_Tab 500mg                     0.024014]
```

I need to convert this data into the following format (list of tuples):

```
[("B11 4BW", "Salbutamol_Inha 100mcg (200 D) CFF", 0.0310589063)
 ("B12 9LP", "Paracet_Tab 500mg",0.024014)]
```

I have tried converting the list to dataframe and other methods and till now I have been unsuccessful. Can someone help?

Comment: Looks like two columns not one series

Comment: My apologies the data has been marked as a list

Comment: How is created Series? do you need first series from list of Series ?

Comment: It's a pandas list not series. I edited the question

Comment: @OmerQureshi - Can you check if working my solution?

Comment: @jezrael - Thank you so much. Yes it's working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is `MultiIndex Series`, so is necessary first [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html),then convert to lists and last to tuples:

Also if need select `Series` from list of `Series` add indexing `[0]`:

```
L = [tuple(x) for x in df[0].reset_index().values.tolist()]
```

Or:

```
L = list(map(tuple, df[0].reset_index().values.tolist()))
```

---

```
print (L)
[('B11 4BW', 'Salbutamol_Inha 100mcg (200 D) CFF', 0.031058999999999996), 
 ('B12 9LP', 'Paracet_Tab 500mg', 0.024013999999999997)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Through pandas, you can do this for get expected result

**Solution**

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.Series(["B11 4BW", "Salbutamol_Inha 100mcg (200 D) CFF", "0.031059"],["B12 9LP", "Paracet_Tab 500mg", "0.024014"])
result = list(zip(data,data.index))
print(result)
```

**Result**

```
[('B11 4BW', 'B12 9LP'),
 ('Salbutamol_Inha 100mcg (200 D) CFF', 'Paracet_Tab 500mg'),
 ('0.031059', '0.024014')]
```

If have any query comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Check with `to_dict`

```
[(x[0][0],x[0][1],x[1]) for x in s.to_dict().items()]
[('B12 9LP', 'Paracet_Tab 500mg', '0.024014'), ('B11 4BW', 'Salbutamol_Inha 100mcg (200 D) CFF', '0.031059')]
```